# Dynamically update syntax highlighting mode rules for the Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, requirejs, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

Totally new to ace editor dev, to dynamically add additional rules to a mode file for syntax highlighting I'm doing an ajax call that sets a global variable that is available inside the mode file to process.

Here is the setup and initial ajax call:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");

$.ajax({
  url: "json-mode-rules.php",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
    window.myModeRules=data; // ("foo","bar","etc")
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
});
```

The mode file is patched with the following:

```
// keywords has already been initialised as an array
// e.g. var keywords = ("and|as|assert...etc")
var extraRules=window.codebenderModeLibrary["myModeRules"].join("|");
keywords=(keywords[0]+"|"+ extraRules);
```

When the page is loaded initallly the ace editor gets all the keywords to syntax highlight. This works great.

The issue is that we have the rules changing when certain events occur and would like the ace editor to refresh its syntax rules.

Doing the ajax call again and calling setMode does nothing - this is due to require js not reloading the file.

I have posted an issue on GitHub without a resolution yet:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1835

> "If you really want to keep global variable, you can wrap everything
>   in a function, call that function to get updated Mode constructor, and
>   then call setMode(new Mode)."

I don't know how to do that and any help would be appreciated.

Anyone with techniques on how to dynamically update ace editor syntax highlighting rules?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/9cbcfb35d3/lib/ace/edit_session.js#L888

`setMode` caches modes, unless they have options
so you can call

```
session.setMode({
   path: "ace/mode/python",
   v: Date.now() 
})
```

to force it to create a new mode.

Another way is to do

```
var DynHighlightRules = function() {
   // add function to change keywords
   this.setKeywords = function(kwMap) {
       this.keywordRule.onMatch = this.createKeywordMapper(kwMap, "identifier")
   }
   this.keywordRule = {
       regex : "\\w+",
       onMatch : function() {return "text"}
   }

   this.$rules = {
        "start" : [
            {
                token: "string",
                start: '"', 
                end: '"',
                next: [{ token : "language.escape", regex : /\\[tn"\\]/}]
            },
            this.keywordRule
        ]
   };
   this.normalizeRules()
};
```

and then whenever highlight rules change do

```
// update keywords
editor.session.$mode.$highlightRules.setKeywords({"keyword": "foo|bar|baz"})
// force rehighlight whole document
editor.session.bgTokenizer.start(0)
```

see http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/445/edit

Comment: Thank you. I'll check both methods as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: Adding the option with the date works. I'll check the other method when I have more time. Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible to use this to change the keywords in ace/mode/javascript?

Comment: I have a similar setup but after bgTokenizer.start(0) the view does not update correctly. The highlighter still highlights the initial rules, but the autocomplete correctly identifies new keywords from new set of rules. What am I missing?

Comment: please show the page with the error, it's not possible to know what you are missing without that

Comment: Does the jsbin example replace the original mode or add to it. How would you start with javascript highlighting and add dynamic words to the javascript highlighting?

Comment: @techdog you'll need to modify source code of the mode. Why do you want to add dynamic words to javascript? there may be another way to achieve same effect

Comment: In my situation the user can create a few custom objects which I would like to highlight along with the regular javascript highlighting. In the jsbin it seems like the dynamic mode replaces the original mode so only the dynamic words highlight.

Comment: Does anyone know how to make a jsbin of the Date.now fix adding some custom keywords to javascript?

Comment: i think yo'll need to copy js mode and modify it

Comment: It is overwriting the existing highlight rules. I tried with python mode and python_highlight_rules. After adding this code, it is not giving me the syntax highlighting for python keywords, operators, etc. Is there any way to not overwrite the existing highlight rules?

Comment: The first suggestion worked for me after importing the necessary modes, e.g.: 
import 'brace/mode/plain_text';