# Ace Code Editor Set Language Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I'm attempting to implement Ace Code Editor with a drop down to select the language. My drop down has an id of mode. I have got the editor to work correctly, but I cannot change the language using the drop down as I would like it to do. My current code is

```
var editor = ace.edit("code");
var textarea = $('textarea[name="code"]').hide();
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");
editor.getSession().setValue(textarea.val());
editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
});

$('#mode').on('change', function(){
var newMode = $("mode").val();
editor.session().setMode({
    path: "ace/mode/" + newMode,
    v: Date.now()});
});
```

As above, this successfully launches the editor, however I can't change the language from SQL, which is the initial language. I came across this question [Dynamically update syntax highlighting mode rules for the Ace Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166784/dynamically-update-syntax-highlighting-mode-rules-for-the-ace-editor)
which is why I've included

```
v: Date.now()
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have a typo in the `editor.session().setMode({` line

use `editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/" + newMode)` instead of it.

`v: Date.now()` was needed to disable caching, you most likely do not need that.

Comment: Thanks worked great. I was getting a second error that newMode was undefined so to fix this I've changed var newMode = $("mode").val(); to var newMode = $(this).val();

Comment: remember to make sure that your editor var is a global, wasted some time trying to figure out why this didn't work for me until I saw that it was a local var

Answer (score 1):

This is correct
**editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + newMode);**

But instead you type editor.session instead of editor.getSession()