# Add additional keywords to a mode at runtime

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way to add and remove additional keywords to a custom mode at runtime?

This has to happen after the mode is set on the session.

In this app, the user can define a list of keywords that they want to be highlighted.

Thanks.

Comment: see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166784/dynamically-update-syntax-highlighting-mode-rules-for-the-ace-editor