# Dynamically update syntax highlighting for the Ace Editor + Requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ace-editor

I need to dynamically change the set of keywords that need to highlight. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166784/dynamically-update-syntax-highlighting-mode-rules-for-the-ace-editor) was the answer to a similar theme, but my project already has require.js and when I use the code from the response then I have an error:

```
Module name "DynHighlightRules" has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

Then I use files from [ace-builds](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds) and try get ace using requirejs. This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #e1 { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 50%;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="e1">
  function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
  }
  first second editor
</div>
  <script src="require.js"></script>

<script>

  require.config({
        baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
            + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),

        paths: {
            ace: "/home/sergey/ace-builds-master/src/",
        }
    });

define("DynHighlightRules", function() {
    this.setKeywords = function(kwMap) {     
        this.keywordRule.onMatch = this.createKeywordMapper(kwMap, "identifier")
    }
    this.keywordRule = {
        regex : "\\w+",
        onMatch : function() {return "text"}
    }

    this.$rules = {
          "start" : [ 
          {
              token: "string",
              start: '"', 
              end: '"',
              next: [{ token : "constant.language.escape.lsl", regex : /\\[tn"\\]/}]
          },
          this.keywordRule
          ]
    };
});

  require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("e1");
    var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
    var dynamicMode = new TextMode();
    dynamicMode.HighlightRules = require(["DynHighlightRules"]); 
    editor.session.setMode(dynamicMode);
    var tags = ["first", "second"];
    dynamicMode.$highlightRules.setKeywords({"keyword": tags.join("|")})
    editor.session.bgTokenizer.start(0)
  });

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

This code not working. How can I add new mode to the ace if I already have requirejs in my project?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have require.js the best solution is to put DynHighlightRules into it's own file, but if you prefer keeping it inline, you can do the following

```
define("DynHighlightRules", function(require, exports, module) {
    var oop = require("ace/lib/oop");
    var TextHighlightRules = require("ace/mode/text_highlight_rules")
          .TextHighlightRules;

    module.exports = function() {
        this.setKeywords = function(kwMap) {
            this.keywordRule.onMatch = this.createKeywordMapper(kwMap, "identifier")
        }
        this.keywordRule = {
            regex: "\\w+",
            onMatch: function() {
                debugger;
                return "text"
            }
        }

        this.$rules = {
            "start": [{
                token: "string",
                start: '"',
                end: '"',
                next: [{
                    token: "constant.language.escape.lsl",
                    regex: /\\[tn"\\]/
                }]
                }, 
                this.keywordRule
            ]
        };
        this.normalizeRules()
    }
    module.exports.prototype = TextHighlightRules.prototype
});

require(["ace/ace", "DynHighlightRules"], function(ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("e1");
    var TextMode = require("ace/mode/text").Mode;
    var dynamicMode = new TextMode();
    dynamicMode.$id = "DynHighlightRules";
    dynamicMode.HighlightRules = require("DynHighlightRules");
    editor.session.setMode(dynamicMode);
    var tags = ["first", "second"];
    dynamicMode.$highlightRules.setKeywords({"keyword": tags.join("|")})
    editor.session.bgTokenizer.start(0)
});
```

note that you should call  `require("DynHighlightRules")`; instead of  `require(["DynHighlightRules"]);` since the later form doesn't return a module/
also DynHighlightRules needs to be in dependency list of main require, to trigger require.js to process queue of pending defines, and you need to set proper prototype and call normalizeRules on text mode enable using rules with start/end