# Dynamic ACE Editor Modes

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm working on an ACE code editor component where each instance has its own changing set of keywords which are passed in to be highlighted.  It is easy enough to update an existing mode and re-run the tokenizer (example: [Dynamically update syntax highlighting mode rules for the Ace Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166784/dynamically-update-syntax-highlighting-mode-rules-for-the-ace-editor)), but with multiple instances I suspect will need to programmatically define new modes and keep them updated.

Is there a good way to do this in ACE?

Comment: this depends on how much you need to modify your mode, if you have same regex, but need to modify values that match it's possible, if it's completely dynamic you may need to implement your tokenizer from scratch

Comment: Yes, it should all be one regex to match a general pattern for a variable name, then the specific variable names if looks for will differ between instances and and over time.  Is there a good pattern for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

if regexes are the same you can create mode as described in the linked question, then use

```
 mode1 = new MyMode()
 editor1.setMode(mode1)
```

so that each instance of the editor, gets its own instance of mode